# fgets funcion in c and odd output

Tags: c

this is my code in vs 2012:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int search( char [],char [], int );
void main(){
    int e;
    char main_string[1000], search_string[50];  
    scanf("%s",&main_string);
    fgets(main_string, 1000, stdin);
    scanf("%s %d",&search_string, &e);
    printf("%u\n", search(main_string, search_string, e));

}
int search( char main_string[] ,char search_string[], int e){
    printf("%s%s\n", main_string, search_string);
    return (unsigned int)strlen(main_string);

}
```

I don t know why just" w w" will be printed and the part before the first whitespace will be ignored?!
and why search function returns real value +1?

Comment: `scanf("%s",&main_string);` eats the part before the first whitespace.

Comment: Or the fact that you're not so much including `stdio` as defining `CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to be some bizarre value. You may also want to tell us what input you're testing with.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill  excuse me.corrected

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik So what`s the solution?

Comment: Don't call `scanf("%s",&main_string);` so it doesn't eat the part before the first whitespace, of course.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik but I wanna get a string withe probable whitespaces.but using scanf lonely gets only the first part before the first whitespace.what is the solution?

Comment: You know it already - you are using `gets` in your program.

Comment: I  didn t figured out.what the solution is finally.@Igor Tandetnik

Comment: I wanna get this sentence with whitespaces completely: "I have read this book" . what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

> I wanna get this sentence with whitespaces completely: "I have read this book" . what should I do?

The `scanf()` function only reads one (whitespace-separated) word at a time. To get a full line of text, use the `fgets()` function instead:

```
fgets(main_string, sizeof(main_string), stdin);
```